# Python3 virtualenv installation borked: No module named 'virtualenv.seed.via_app_data'

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv, modulenotfounderror

I am on a MAC OS 10.15.6
I am having a tough time with virtualenv for python3.

The error I keep getting

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv.seed.via_app_data'
```

It pops up when I run the following command (among others)

```
python3 -m virtualenv
```

What I have tried

- Pip installing virtualenv with sudo
- Regular pip install, normal permissions
- Using the pip install --user option
- Trying older versions of virtualenv (20.0.23)
- Trying newer version of virtualenv (20.0.31)

Any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

Exactly same problem!

I uninstalled **virtualenv**, and now it works!

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
```

I don't know why

Maybe python now comes with a built-in version of virtualenv?

I'm on **python 3.8**

Comment: When I uninstall virtualenv, I get an error when poetry tries to create a virtaul environment:

$ poetry add fastapi
Creating virtualenv my-test-proj-pMYfjoa5-py3.8 in /home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
usage: virtualenv [--version] ....


virtualenv: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-periodic-update

Comment: Also worked for me. Just uninstall (without installing again). What is going on?